# Is ordinal regression with mixed effects in this design the correct choice?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, ordinal-data

I am struggling to choose the correct test procedure for the following data and hypothesis:

Variable A: 3 levels, fixed effect, signifies the grammatical gender of a noun
Variable B: 2 levels, fixed effect, signifies gender of the participant who used that noun
Variable C: 30 unique values, random effect, signifies different nouns which each have a certain grammatical gender
response variable Y: ordinal values (1-5)

So there are 10 instances of C per level of A with various numbers of observations each.

The Null hypthesis are that A has no effect on Y, B has no effect on Y, and that there is no interaction between A and B.

Can I model this via ordinal regression with mixed effects, using random slopes for C, and testing for significance of A and B and the interaction? Or should I use some different hypthesis testing, maybe a non-parametric test?

Kind regards,
Josephine

Comment: Does each level of *C* have only one gender ?  Or is it a word can have different genders ?  (like hermana / hermano in Spanish would have one level in *C*).

Comment: Yes each level of C only has one gender

Comment: What you are proposing makes sense.  Mixed effects ordinal regression would be better than trying to use a nonparametric method.

Comment: Thanks. So when testing the variables and their interaction for significance, can I use a LRT via anova(model_full,model_without_factor1,test="Chisq")? The resulting p-values are confusing, as they are different then expected after a descriptive analysis. One variable has a relatively low p-value (not signifcant though) despite a negligible difference in means between the levels of that variable.

Comment: What function are you using to fit the ordinal regression model ?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, this question referred to a model with a numeric target variable, using lme4::lmer(). I am doing two regression models with different target variables but same setup otherwise, which I did not mention in the first post.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use the lmerTest package to get the anova table ?